# Pomelo Unknown column 'X' in 'field list'

Tags: c#, .net-core, openiddict, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

On Use of OpeniddictCore (https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) with MySQL using
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql), I get the following error. I think its a Pomelo library issue but I am not sure.

Can someone help?

*MySqlException: Unknown column 'o.DisplayNames' in 'field list'
MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask<ArraySegment> task) in ServerSession.cs, line 806
MySqlException: Unknown column 'o.DisplayNames' in 'field list'
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet() in MySqlDataReader.cs, line 130

---

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'o.DisplayNames' in 'field list'
at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 806
at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 51*

Comment: It means your `DbContext` has  `DisplayNames` column mapping but this column missing in DB

Comment: So OpenIddict actually creates the table in a blank DB upon initiation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenidDict but looking into samples code there is a class `ApplicationDbContext` inheriting from `IdentityDbContext`. You db should be aligned with this DbContext. One of ways to achieve this is creating and running [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Unknown column 'X' in 'field list'
#1375](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1375) on our GitHub repo, @Amyn solved this issue:

> This is very likely just a configuration/setup issue with the technologies you are using. [...]

> Thanks you. You are right, there was a issue on my side. I made it work on SQL Server and then changed to mySQL and it worked fine. Sorry about it. Please delete the issue , as its irrelevant.